# poetry install doesnt create .env folder inside project folder with Anaconda python 3.9 env

Tags: anaconda3, python-poetry

I have anaconda 3.8 on windows 10. I created python3.9 virtual environment and set poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true. But when I do poetry install it doesnt create the .envn folder inside the project. Below is the poetry env info results:

```
(python39) C:\Users\username\Developer\Packages\test5>poetry env info

Virtualenv

Python:         3.9.6

Implementation: CPython

Path:           C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\python39

Valid:          True


System

Platform: win32

OS:       nt

Python:   C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\python39***
```

However, when deactivate the python39 environment and run poetry install it creates the .envn folder inside project. and the poetry env info results the following:

```
Virtualenv

Python: 3.9.6

Implementation: CPython

Path: C:\Users\username\Developer\Packages\test2\.venv

Valid: True


System

Platform: win32

OS: nt

Python: C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\python39
```

how can I make it work in python39 environment?

Answer (score 6):

This is an expected behavior. Whenever poetry detect it's running within a virtual environment it will not create a new one ( Exception: condas "base" environment is not detected as a virtual environment).

To create an in-project venv for python3.9 using conda you can do this:

- set the config to `virtualenvs.in-project true`
- without being in a venv run `poetry env use /path/to/python3.9` once
- run `poetry install`

Also have a look into the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/#switching-between-environments) about `poetry env use`.

(Question and are answer are cross-posted in [poetry's issue tracker](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4490))

Comment: `run` is not required when setting `poetry env use /path/to/python3.9`